# How can I integrate JSF with REST?

Tags: jsf

I have created a REST service for uploading files. Because of various requirements, I cannot integrate that into the JSF lifecycle. Amongst others:

- JQuery handles the `POST` and expects a `JSON` response which I don't feel good doing from a `bean` method.
- Fileupload plugin does multiple concurrent file `POST` s, which AFAIK is not possible (by default) JSF behaviour as event's will be queued.

I have a few options in mind, but I would like to be as intrusive as possible. The ones I have examined so far are:

- Using JQuery, populate a `hidden` field with the location of the files and process them in the `ActionListener`
- Same as above, but also call the `ActionListener` from JQuery
- Store data in the session (since I can access it, from my REST service)
- Use an `@EJB` queue service to pass the data to the `bean` (`@Inject' service to both`bean`and`REST` service)

Alternatively, is there a way to actually fetch by `@ViewScoped` bean given that I have the `viewstate` form field?